# JAVA: Writing a textfile in classpath?

Tags: java

i want to write a file in the directory, where my main.class also is.
This always gets an error:

```
File file = new File(main.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));
```

That isn't working too:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource(AsStream)("me.test.test.txt"));
```

It always says, that The constructor File(InputStream) is undefined.
Anyone an idea?

Regards,

Comment: Why specifically here? You can set up an external, well defined directory instead

Comment: Generally you can't write to the classpath. Your class may very well reside in a read-only JAR file.

Comment: In general you can't do this. The elements of a CLASSPATH should be treated as read-only. Consider a JAR or non-unpacked WAR file for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write in this stream, it is an InputStream. You should create a FileOutpuStream, based on the path provided by getResource("test.txt").

If the file already exists :

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(Main.class.getResource("/toto.txt").getFile());
```

If it does not exist yet :

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(Main.class.getResource("/").getFile() + "toto.txt");
```

But, be careful, the location can be in a jar file, then it can be read only.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
File file=(new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()));
```

the file object represent the directory where your main.class file is located at runtime.

after that create new file as:
    File txtFile=new File(file,"myText.txt");